# moving all the .pdf files from the subdirectories to the directory of the same name created in the root directory inside the directory called "PDF"

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file to move all the pdf files from the sub folders to the folder "PDF" created in the root directory while running the batch.
Now I required to create the Sub folders of the same name which contains pdf files inside the "PDF" folder in the root directory and move the pdf files to the respective sub folders.
I have mentioned my code below,please provide me a modified code to get an appropriate result.

```
md PDF
for /r "%cd%" %%x in ("*.pdf") do (move "%%x" "%cd%\PDF")
```

Thanks in Advance
Vijistha

Comment: If you are trying to replicate the folder structure, is there any reason for not using xcopy or robocopy?

Comment: yes, As I am using DZBatcher for converting FM files to .pdf files. I am not able to work with Xcopy command (when I use this command its showing an error like its not an internal or external command ) :(

Answer (score 0):

This should create folders in the PDF directory with the name of the PDF file and then and move the PDF file into the folder.

It will repeat for every PDF file so each folder will contain one PDF file.

Change `d:\pdf` as necessary and test it on some sample files.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("d:\pdf\*.pdf") do (
   md "%%~dpa\%%~na"
   move "%%a" "%%~dpa\%%~na"
)
```